# What is the __expr-val-dir html tag attribute in SharePoint master pages for?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, xhtml

This non-compliant, mysterious attribute seems to be simply a copy of the dir attribute, but I cannot find any reference to it or example of it being used anywhere.  Can anyone shed some light on where it came from and/or if there is any use for it (other than to help SharePoint be a little more non-standards bases)?

Comment: I see it also in the Dubai government site as `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" __expr-val-dir="ltr" lang="ar-sa" dir="rtl">`